# How to see if MacBook Air is "talking to" USB to Ethernet adaptor (without an Ethernet device at the other end)?

Tags: network, usb, ethernet

I've been using an Apple USB to Ethernet adaptor plus a short Ethernet cable to connect to an Ether net device (Raspberry Pi in thins case).

Normally when I connect the lights blink on the device and everything works nicely using VNC Viewer.

Today no blinking lights or connection.

Is there a way I can check to see if I at least have a USB connection from my MacBook Air to the Apple USB/Ethernet converting dongle? Something I can do on my laptop that shows the dongle is there and connected by itself?

I'd like to check that part if possible as the first step in debugging my connect problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the Mac sees the Ethernet adapter by doing [Apple menu] / About this Mac, clicking System Report, and then looking at USB in the Hardware section.

Comment: There it is; https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ7mg.png Thank you!